# Receiving garbled data when reading a NetworkStream in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to receive data using a TcpListener in C# . I have the listener working, but when I make a HTTP request to it using my web browser, I just get garbled data when converted to ASCII. It seems like its skipping bytes?

```cs
while (client.Connected)
{
    if (stream.ReadByte() != -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Recieving data");
        byte[] buf = new byte[0];
        byte data;
        while (stream.ReadByte() != -1)
        {
            data = (byte) stream.ReadByte();
            Console.Write("{0} ", data.ToString("x"));
            buf.Append(data);
        }
        dataRecieved(buf);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
54 2f 48 54 2f 2e d 48 73 3a 6c 63 6c 6f 74 38 38 d 43 6e 65 74 6f 3a 6b 65 2d 6c 76 d 43 63 65 43 6e 72 6c 20 61 2d 67 3d d 55 67 61 65 49 73 63 72 2d 65 75 73 73 20 d 55 65 2d 67 6e 3a 4d 7a 6c 61 35 30 28 69 64 77 20 54 31 2e 3b 57 6e 34 20 36 29 41 70 65 65 4b 74 35 37 33 20 4b 54 4c 20 69 65 47 63 6f 20 68 6f 65 31 33 30 35 36 2e 33 20 61 61 69 35 37 33 d 41 63 70 2d 61 67 61 65 20 6e 55 d 41 63 70 3a 74 78 2f 74 6c 61 70 69 61 69 6e 78 74 6c 78 6c 61 70 69 61 69 6e 78 6c 71 30 39 69 61 65 61 69 2c 6d 67 2f 65 70 69 61 65 61 6e 2c 2f 3b 3d 2e 2c 70 6c 63 74 6f 2f 69 6e 64 65 63 61 67 3b 3d 33 71 30 39 a 65 2d 50 3a 31 a 65 2d 65 63 2d 69 65 20 6f 65 a 65 2d 65 63 2d 6f 65 20 61 69 61 65 a 65 2d 65 63 2d 73 72 20 31 a 65 2d 65 63 2d 65 74 20 6f 75 65 74 a 63 65 74 45 63 64 6e 3a 67 69 2c 64 66 61 65 20 72 a a
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: every time you call `stream.ReadByte();` it reads the *next* available byte. The current byte is discarded unless you save it in your code. So something like `while (stream.ReadByte() != -1)` does read in a byte and check to see if its -1, but then since you don't save it it gets thrown away.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Ok. Changed the if statement to `if (stream.DataAvailable)` and the inner while loop to `while ((data = (byte) stream.ReadByte()) != -1 ) `. But when I send data using a TcpClient, I now get `FF`s  after the data?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are getting UTF8 Data from the stream. You will have to deal with the encoding

Try something like this.

```csharp
private string ReadUTF8String(Stream stream)
{
    using var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var buffer = new byte[4096];
    int readCount;
    while ((readCount = stream.Read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
    }

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}


while (client.Connected)
{
    if (stream.ReadByte() != -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Recieving data");
        string result = ReadUTF8String(stream);
        Console.Write(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, I tried converting to ASCII, Unicode and UTF-8.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar No, the problem i was having was that I wasn't saving the byte in the while loop, so it would just skip every other byte.

Comment: @sfs I think the problem with Kevin's method is that `stream.Read` returning a non-positive value would mean that the stream is closed. The problem is that an HTTP request terminates with \r\n\r\n but the connection doesn't close, so it will just keep waiting for more data from the client. You need to read while there's data until the last 4 characters are \r\n\r\n.

Comment: I used `if (ms.Length >= 4) { ms.Seek(-4, SeekOrigin.Current); ms.Read(buffer, 0, 4); if (buffer[0] == 13 && buffer[1] == 10 && buffer[2] == 13 && buffer[3] == 10) { break; } }` below Kevins' `ms.Write` line and it worked.